# In Discriminant Analysis (SPSS), why there are F values of the canonical functions?

Tags: statistics

Recently, I read a paper in which the author uses Discriminant Analysis, here is his words:

"The discriminant analysis produced three significant canonical functions (Function 1, F(18, 2130) = 164.81, p<0.0001; Function 2, F(10, 1508) = 85.43, p<0.0001; Function 3, F(4, 755) = 22.93, p<0.0001)."

I didn't found anything associated with F values of canonical functions in the result of DA done by SPSS, and I can not understand the F values of the canonical functions, anyone could explained to me?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the F-test under the "Wilks' lambda" section of SPSS output. In this section, SPSS reports not only the lambda statistic, but also the F-value relative to the chi-square statistic for the canonical functions.

Comment: But there is only dfB， no dfW，right？ How to calculate the dfW？

Comment: Simply remind that $dfB+dfW=dfT$, where $dfT$ is the total number of degrees of freedom.